# How to resolve the Dapper System.Data.DataException HResult=0x80131501 InvalidCastException Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Uri'

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

Recently, I refactored some code which resulted in changing the type of some properties of an entity from `System.String` to `System.URI`. The names of the properties in question contained the substring URI or URL and the [SonarLint](https://www.sonarlint.org/) static code analyzer was recommending that the code be refactored to use the `System.URI` type instead of `System.String` for those properties, which makes sense in our solution.

In this project, we are leveraging StackExchange's [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) as an ultra fast and light object mapper, but after the refactoring, I started receiving this error when trying to retrieve data from my repository:

```
System.Data.DataException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message=Error parsing column 5 (RequestUrl=https://www.myurl.com/api/wow - String)
  Source=Dapper
  StackTrace:
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.ThrowDataException(Exception ex, Int32 index, IDataReader reader, Object value) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 3609
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<>c__DisplayClass156_0`8.<GenerateMapper>b__1(IDataReader r) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 1544
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<MultiMapImpl>d__153`8.MoveNext() in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:line 1444
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<MultiMapAsync>d__52`8.MoveNext() in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.Async.cs:line 949
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at My.Namespace.MyRepository.<GetAllRepositoryMethod>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\dev\repos\myproject\MyRepository.cs:line 59
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at My.Namespace.Program.CallerMethod(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) in C:\dev\repos\myproject\Program.cs:line 109
   at System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(Object state)

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Uri'.
```

How can I get around this error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turns out that Dapper is easily extensible and by declaring a simple class that extends `SqlMapper.TypeHandler<T>`, you can define a mapping (TypeHandler) between the `System.String` and `System.URI` types and enable Dapper to perform the cast.

Here's what that class looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Dapper;

namespace My.Namespace.Data.DatabaseTools
{
    public class DapperUriTypeHandler : SqlMapper.TypeHandler<Uri>
    {
        public override void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, Uri value)
        {
            parameter.Value = value.ToString();
        }

        public override Uri Parse(object value)
        {
            return new Uri((string)value);
        }
    }    
}
```

Once you have declared the mapping, you can let Dapper know about it by calling the `SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler` method and providing an instance of your custom type handler class as a parameter like so:

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(new DapperUriTypeHandler());
```

The best place to call `SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler` is somewhere in your startup configuration so that the type handler is known to Dapper early on in the execution of your application or service.

I Hope this can help other community members resolve similar issues with Dapper and type casting quickly in the future!